# dynamic add elements, dragable and sortable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hi I am having a hard time doing my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kodewrecker/mRyVp/552/)  
what I like to do is:
 1. Dynamic Add group
 2. Dynamic Add question
 3. Sortable Group
 4. Sortable Question
 5. Question can be drop to another group

but the fiddle does only :
 1. Dynamic Add group
 2. Dynamic Add question
4. Sortable Question

also the generated input is disabled how is that?

could anyone help me please? 
I'm a backend guy so please spare me.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the disabled inputs, you could try removing the '.disableSelection()' codes.

---

Here is an updated version of the fiddle : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mRyVp/565/). What I did was:

Removed all of the disableSelection() codes. 
Created a common sortable container and attached all the sortable in the classes. This way, multiple `questions` can be transferred from one container to the other.
Added a min-height property to the containers. You need this height to add an element back to the main container.

Hope this helps pards!

Comment: @kodewrecker Here is an updated version of the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mRyVp/562/). There are variables that are used but undeclared, and there are elements in which the sortable functions are anchored. I managed to answer 1,2,3,4. With number 5, im still working on it.

Comment: big thanks for that fiddle, big thanks for taking time on this. big thanks!

Comment: you're the man, I also edit the first fiddle you altered and I too got it right, but you're 27mins first, my fiddles here http://jsfiddle.net/kodewrecker/mRyVp/567/ . thanks for this man. thank you!

Comment: Thanks bro! By the way, the new fiddle fixed the bug on the first one, where you cant move any "questions" without adding a new element. Just to let you know. Good luck! Cheers!

Comment: yeah, that's far more better that what I did. thanks big help